# How to build a big C++ project with multiple internal dependencies with Cmake?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, structure

I'm starting to work on a big C++ projects and have questions about structuring it. The project contains two applications: A server `ServerMain` and a client `ClientMain`.

I want my project to have the following structure:

```
project/
├── cmake-build-release/
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   └── ...
│
├── lib/
│   ├── comp1/
│   │   ├── CmakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── a1.hpp
│   │   ├── a1.cpp
│   │   ├── b1.hpp
│   │   └── b1.cpp
│   ├── comp2/
│   │   ├── CmakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── a2.hpp
│   │   ├── a2.cpp
│   │   ├── b2.hpp
│   │   └── b2.cpp
│   └── comp3/
│       ├── CmakeLists.txt
│       ├── a3.hpp
│       ├── a3.cpp
│       ├── b3.hpp
│       └── b3.cpp
│
└── app/
    ├── CmakeLists.txt
    ├── ServerMain.cpp
    └── ClientMain.cpp
```

Now, both applications depend on different components and some of the components depend onto other components. Secondly, all of my includes should look like that:

- `ServerMain` depends onto `a1.hpp`: `#include<comp1/a1.hpp>`
- `ClientMain` depends onto `a2.hpp`: `#include<comp2/a2.hpp>`
- `a1` and `a2` depend onto `b3.hpp`: `#include<comp3/b3.hpp>`

So, my question is:
How to handle does components with Cmake? How should the different Components include each other to allow for those cross decencies? Can you give me additional tips regarding the structure of the project?

Comment: You need to use `target_link_library` and similar to tell CMake about the dependencies in your project - it can't figure that out by itself.